# <T extends Enum<T>> T[] as a return type in Java 8

Tags: generics, java-8

I am looking at some code which compiles in java 7 but fails to compile in Java 8.

```
class Test {
    public <T extends Enum<T>> T[] doSomething(...) {...}

    public <T extends Enum<T>> T[] methodWhichCallsDoSomething() {
        ...
        return doSomething(...);
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible upper bounds java.lang.Enum<T>,T
```

I am running jdk 1.8.0_71.

Does anyone know a workaround or solution for getting this to compile and work in Java 8?

EDIT: The error message is given for the line calling doSomething(), for the col just before the parenthesis.

Comment: I am wondering why you want to do that. If more than one method in your code is using the same T, why dont you put it on the class?

Comment: Compiles fine with every Java 8 version. Maybe the problem lies in the `...` part.

Comment: How did you make sure it compiled against every version?

Comment: I've edited to provide further information about the error given.

Comment: I wouldn’t call this “further information”. When the compiler rejects your method invocation, it doesn’t matter whether it does so by pointing at the first `d` or at the last `)` or somewhere in between. Regarding your other question, I tested it by using a script that runs through all JDK releases and compiles the specified code.

Comment: If at least one of `doSomething`’s parameters refers to `T` in any way, it is impossible for `methodWhichCallsDoSomething` to provide correct arguments (unless all are `null`), as no appropriate variable is in scope. It’s very likely that the code compiled either, due to a compiler error or an unchecked operation, and in either case, it is indeed possible that this has changed. A parameter-less method like `methodWhichCallsDoSomething()` promising to return whatever `T[]` the caller wishes, is broken anyway. There are several examples for similar anti-patterns, failing now under Java 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by what you are passing to `doSomething`. You didn’t post the actual arguments, but from the signature we can deduce that, if at least one of `doSomething`’s parameters refers to `T` in any way, it is impossible for `methodWhichCallsDoSomething` to provide correct arguments (unless all are `null`), as no appropriate variable is in scope.

It’s very likely that the code compiled either, due to a compiler error or an unchecked operation, and in either case, it is indeed possible that this behavior has changed due to the new type inference rules.

A parameter-less method like `methodWhichCallsDoSomething()` promising to return whatever `T[]` the caller wishes, is broken anyway. There are several examples for similar anti-patterns, failing now under Java 8, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39021934/2711488) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28466925/2711488). If such code happened to work in earlier version, it happened to work by accident and the problem occurring now were actually already there before.

For such broken code, getting a compiler error now, is the better of the possible symptoms as sometime, the code still compiles, but will suddenly break at runtime.