# Stream collect with Generic type

Tags: java, java-8

I´m trying to use generic in a method where I deserializing a json into pojo so it could return whatever object type.

Here my code:

```
private Bla(List<A> as, List<B> bs)
{
    this.as = as;
    this.bs = bs;
}

public static Bla from(JsonObject json)
{
    return new Bla(Bla.<A>load(json, As), Bla.<B>load(json, Bs));
}

private static <T> List<T> load(JsonObject jsonObject, String param)
{
    return jsonObject.getJsonArray(param).stream()
                                         .map(Bla::getItem)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static <T> T getItem(Object json)
{
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(json.toString(), new TypeReference<T>() {
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error parsing json items", e);
    }
}
```

The problem is that `.collect(Collectors.toList());` seems not compile cause cannot resolve the instance type.

The compilation error is:

```
Error:(43, 25) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: T
        lower bounds: java.lang.Object
```

To avoid confusion in my example A and B are Pojos

Regards.

Comment: Can you post `Bla` two argument constructor? See this also about your methods returning any `T` http://stackoverflow.com/a/40245602/1743880

Comment: Regardless of any generic issue here with `collect`, your `getItem` method is broken. `new TypeReference<T>` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Post compiler error, please.

Comment: I update adding the constructor in the question. @SotiriosDelimanolis any idea if it´s possible in a different way?

Comment: This may be too much for type inference since you need to propagate `T` back from `collect` to `map`. Try `map(x -> Bla.<T>getItem(x))`. Another option is adding a second `map(x -> (T) x)` after the existing `map`.

Comment: Not that this code won’t work anyway. At the place where you instantiate, `new TypeReference<T>() {}`, nobody knows what `T` actually is. Even its caller, `load`, has no idea of `A` or `B`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Brilliant Marko!, that solve the problem!.

Comment: Yes, @Holger, I think this should fail compilation.

Comment: The example is still far from being complete. What are `<A>` and `<B>`? They look like type parameters of the class `Bla` but `Bla` is used as raw type in `new Bla`....

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: it will compile, as the requirement of `T` being reifiable can’t be expressed for `TypeReference`. It will fail at runtime.

Comment: A and B are Pojos

Comment: @Holger But the compiler must know the value of `T` to create the anonymous class. How does that work out?

Comment: Try using `.map(Bla::<T>getItem)` in place of `.map(Bla::getItem)`.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: no, it doesn’t need to be a reifiable type from the compiler’s perspective, as long as the correctness can be proven, which is easy for a class which doesn’t actually use `T`. The attempt to inspect `T` at runtime is not visible to the compiler here. It will be [`TypeVariable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html) then, where the Json mapper wishes to get a `Class`…

Comment: @Tunaki : `Bla` doesn’t have to be a generic type for making this code correct. If `Bla` is a non-generic type, the code is correct from the generic type system’s perspective. Yet, the desire to create `A` or `B` instances as needed at runtime won’t work due to type erasure.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik your suggestion works fine in runtime, thanks again man!, well and thank you all guys for so interesting discussion. Mark do you want create an official response to mark as resolved. I think this question will help people in the future. Even me again  :)

Comment: It's unclear to me why you're going through this whole dance. Just deserialize the json containing the arrays into a `Bla` directly. Use a mixin if you need to.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you provide a code example?, not quite sure that I follow mate

Comment: Just `mapper.readValue(jsonObject.toString(), Bla.class)`. It's also unclear why you're using two different JSON parsing libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's examine this method:

```
private static <T> List<T> load(JsonObject jsonObject, String param)
{
    return jsonObject.getJsonArray(param).stream()
                                         .map(Bla::getItem)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The type of the last step, `Collectors.toList()` must be `List<T>`, but to get it the type of the previous step, `Bla::getItem` must be inferred as `T getItem`. Since `getItem` is a generic method, this needs a complex pattern of type constraint propagation which is apparently more than Java's type inference will handle. To solve this, help the compiler with a hint:

```
.map(Bla::<T>getItem)
```

(credit for this syntactic variant goes to user Nándor Előd Fekete).

A second issue is your `getItem` method:

```
private static <T> T getItem(Object json)
{
    return mapper.readValue(json.toString(), new TypeReference<T>() {};
}
```

Using `TypeReference` here doesn't help because `T` is not a concrete type. It will remain non-reified in the anonymous class that the compiler creates here, therefore Jackson will get no helpful hint from it. You can just use a simpler `readValue` signature that doesn't take the `TypeReference`.